# Django save database the current context

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a table called `Trend` which contains the following fields:

```
class Trend(models.Model):
   title             = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   long_description  = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
   date              = models.DateField('data published')
   rating            = models.IntegerField()
   picture           = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
   category          = models.ForeignKey(Geographic, related_name='entries')
```

I send the data of this table through `context` and I show the information with a table. In the same page I have some forms to create filters in the `Trends` then after applying these filters to the content of the table I want to allow the user to save that information.

Basically, I want to get the current context:

```
trend = Trend.objects.filter(Q(category__country__contains='Denmark'))
return render(request, "trend-list.html", "{"trends":trend})
```

Then save the current trend list into a new database, the model of the table is the following:

```
class TrendLists(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    list = models.ManyToManyField(Trend)
    data = models.DateField()
```

My question is

How can a get the current context of the page to save the information in the database?

I hope we can find a solution together.

UPDATE by request.

I cannot add all the code because it is too much, but this is the part of the table and the form that I am using to ask for the name of the trend list.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#name_list_trend" class="btn" style="color:white; background: #415dff;">Gem som ny liste</a> <!-- Save the list -->
    <input type="button" value="Vaelg tilfaeldige">
    <input class="input_orange" type="button" value="Sorter efter sogeord">
    <input type="text">
</form>

{% comment %} MODAL window to introduce the name of the list {% endcomment %}
<div id="name_list_trend" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Do you want to save the current trend list?</h3><br>
        <h3>Introduce the name of the list:</h3>
    </div>
    <form action="#" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label for="name_list">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name_trend_list" value="" id="name_list" />
            <input type="text" value="" name="trends" style="display:none;">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Send >>">
        </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-striped" >
        {% comment %} Check if there are elements in the trend list{% endcomment %}
        {% if trends %}
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        {% endif %}
        <tbody>
            {% for trend in trends %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="trend_star_{{ trend.rating }}"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ trend.picture }}" title="{{ trend.title }}">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="trend_description">
                        <h2>{{ trend.title }}</h2>
                        <div><p>{{ trend.short_description }}</p></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ trend.date|date:"d/m/Y" }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{% url read_trend trend.pk %}"  class="btn">Read</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you can see I don't know how to handle the form, because I don't know how to get the current context `trends` and save in the `Trendlist` database.

Perhaps, I am thinking the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Can you post your template and form code, so that it will be easy for us to help?

Comment: I hope with the template that I just added, you can understand my problem.